# Data truncation con un BigDecimal JAVA y SQL

Tags: java, mysql

estoy intentando insertar un número grande en una base de datos SQL y me sale este error:
Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'valor_estimado' at row 1

En la base de datos tengo definido la columna donde va este vamos como DECIMAL(11,2), y el valor en cuestión es 438484335.96, definido como BigDecimal. Os dejo el código para que quede más claro:

```
sentencia.setBigDecimal("valor_estimado", entry.getContractFolderStatus().getProcurementProject().getBudgetAmount().getEstimatedOverallContractAmount());
sentencia.setBigDecimal("presupuesto_sin_impuestos", entry.getContractFolderStatus().getProcurementProject().getBudgetAmount().getTaxExclusiveAmount());
sentencia.setBigDecimal("presupuesto_con_impuestos", entry.getContractFolderStatus().getProcurementProject().getBudgetAmount().getTotalAmount());
sentencia.execute();
```

La tabla en cuestión es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: Sale DECIMAL(10,2), pero es (11,2). Todavía no está actualizado porque ese es el esquema ER, y yo estoy trabajando ya con el script importando a la base de datos, y la columna modificada.

PD2: La decisión de usar BigDecimal se debe a que hay números que si los recojo como Double, me los recoge con notación científica, y no me interesa eso, pues quiero guardar el número al "natural".

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_expedientes` (
  `expedientes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(2500) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_actualizacion` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `objeto_contrato` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `valor_estimado` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `presupuesto_sin_impuestos` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `presupuesto_con_impuestos` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `duracion` decimal(17,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unitcode` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `typecode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subtypecode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`expedientes`),
  KEY `typecode_idx` (`typecode`),
  KEY `subtypecode_idx` (`subtypecode`),
  CONSTRAINT `subtypecode` FOREIGN KEY (`subtypecode`) REFERENCES `tbl_subtype_code` (`code`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `typecode` FOREIGN KEY (`typecode`) REFERENCES `tbl_type_code` (`code`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Código para la obtención del valor a insertar:

```
private BigDecimal estimatedOverallContractAmount
public void readAttributes(){

  double estimatedOverallContractAmount = -1.0;

  estimatedOverallContractAmountNode = budgetAmount.getElementsByTagName("cbc:EstimatedOverallContractAmount").item(POS_UNICO_ELEMENTO);
  try{
    estimatedOverallContractAmount = Double.parseDouble(estimatedOverallContractAmountNode.getTextContent());       
            
    this.estimatedOverallContractAmount = BigDecimal.valueOf(estimatedOverallContractAmount);
  }catch (NullPointerException e){
    e.print();
  }
}
```

Comment: Muestranos el `SHOW CREATE TABLE nombreDeLaTabla;` en vez de una imagen no actualizada. Muéstranos también la forma en que obtienes el valor que intentas insertar. Y dinos qué ocurre si intentas insertar ese mismo valor directamente en la BD.

Comment: Listo. Si intento hacerlo medianto un INSERT en la BD directamente me lo permite. Y estos usando el mismo número que en JAVA.

Comment: Correcto, acabo de hacer una prueba y el valor `438484335.96` se inserta sin ningún problema. Por eso mismo te dije que nos mostraras de qué modo obtienes el valor que intentas insertar. Obtenlo en una variable y muéstralo. No podemos ver si los métodos que llamas ahi te están garantizando un número correcto para la inserción.

Comment: Vale, te dejo el código de obtención también. Gracias.

Comment: El método que llamas para obtener el valor es este (de la instancia `entry`):  `getContractFolderStatus().getProcurementProject().getBudgetAmount().getEstimatedOverallContractAmount()` ¿Dónde está ese método?

Comment: En la clase BudgetAmount, es una variable de dicha clase. Es un getter normal que devuelve el valor almacenado. La lectura de la variable se hace en la clase BudgetAmount con el código que puse en la pregunta. Lo raro es que si es un número más pequeño todo funciona correctamente, solo pasa esto con números grandes, y por más que aumente el DECIMAL de SQL sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124112/discussion-between-lretro-and-a-cedano).